# Can't connect to localhost from my mobile

Tags: mongodb, networking, localhost

I developed some simple microservices that take data from a MongoDB database and return them in JSON format.

The database is on my machine, and so are the microservices.
When I start a microservices I can access data on my machine, for example connecting to

```
http://localhost:7003/projects
```

on my browser.

I want to get the data from my mobile phone too. So I connected it to the same network, and from my computer, using the `ipconfig` command I found that the IP address of the pc is `192.168.1.63`

If I try to connect to `http://192.168.1.63:7003/projects` I can't get the data, though.

I searched for some solutions but I found nothing. Am I skipping some step?

Comment: Is the port to your database open?

Comment: This can have several reasons. Which Language did you use to create the microservice? Is there a router or a managed switch between the two clients? Is the Web server restricting anything other than localhost source? Is your windows firewall active?

Comment: Have to check if the port is open. It's my very first time using these technologies.

Comment: Microservices are made in Java using Javalin and Vert.x frameworks

Comment: Tried to use the bind IP to connect to Mongo in the microservices (`127.0.0.1` and not `localhost`) and to disable Windows Firewall, but didn't worked.